# Do I need to explicitly "end" Firebase Cloud Functions triggered by Firestore events?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In **HTTP functions** for Firebase, we get that:

> Terminate HTTP Functions [DOC link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions)
>
> Always end an HTTP function with send(), redirect(), or end(). **Otherwise, your function might continue to run and be forcibly terminated by the system**. See also Sync, Async and Promises.

**QUESTION**

**Is something similar necessary to other types of functions like the ones triggered by Firestore events?**

Do I need to return something (even if it's null) or some other command to explicitly end it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official documentation about [Terminating background functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#functions_background_terminate-node8up)

> You must signal when background functions have completed. Otherwise,
>   your function can continue to run and be forcibly terminated by the
>   system. You can signal function completion in each runtime as
>   described below:
>
> In the Node.js runtimes version 8 and above, signal function
>   completion by either:
>
> 1.Invoking the callback argument
>
> 2.Returning a Promise
>
> 3.Wrapping your function using the async keyword (which causes your function to implicitly return a Promise)
>
> 4.Returning a value.
>
> If invoking the callback argument or synchronously returning a value,
>   ensure that all asynchronous processes have completed first. If
>   returning a Promise, Cloud Functions ensures that the Promise is
>   settled before terminating.

Answer (score 6):

> Is something similar necessary to other types of functions like the
>   ones triggered by Firestore events?

All the other types of Cloud Functions (i.e. all Cloud Functions except the HTTP Cloud Functions) require that you **return a promise** that will resolve when the asynchronous work is complete. This includes background triggered Cloud Functions (e.g. the ones triggered by Firestore events).

If your Cloud Function does not include asynchronous operation(s), you can return a simple value, like `null` when all the work is finished. You would also do this in case you want to cancel the Cloud Function execution, for example if a pre-condition is not fulfilled. The official Cloud Functions samples show several examples, in particular [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/6c284a689c484ac4395fde1a8e8d6c2731705b55/remote-config-diff/functions/index.js) an [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/6c284a689c484ac4395fde1a8e8d6c2731705b55/child-count/functions/index.js).

---

I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ which explains that in detail.